# Вывести атрибут XML тега

Tags: php, xml

Есть вот такой файл к xml

```
<currency_list>
<USD sel="48.75" buy="49.75"/>
<EUR sel="54.75" buy="56.00"/>
<GBP sel="" buy=""/>
<time time="1458"/>
</currency_list>
```

Как мне вывести исключительно число 1458?
Пытаюсь так:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('/currency.xml');
print_r($xml);
```

тогда выводится

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [USD] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [sel] => 48.75 [buy] => 49.75 ) ) [EUR] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [sel] => 54.75 [buy] => 56.00 ) ) [GBP] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [sel] => [buy] => ) ) [time] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [time] => 1458 ) ) )
```

Если

```
print_r($xml->currency_list); //выводится SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

а если

```
  print_r($xml->time); //SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [time] => 1458 ) )
```

и как мне вывести только 1458?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print_r ($xml->time->attributes()['time']);
```

Простой метод [attributes()](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) (посмотрите еще пару верхних комментариев, там есть полезные хелперы)

Comment: по вашей строке syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Comment: все равно та же ошибка

Comment: версия php 5.3?

Comment: @Etki да, foreach($xml->time[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
} // а если так то time="1458"

Comment: 5.3 не поддерживает дереференс элементов массива прямо по возврату из функции. Сохраните промежуточный результат в массив и достаньте этот ключ из него.

Comment: @Etki все проще оказалось, после foreach переменная $b это и есть нужное мне число, спасибо

Comment: Это настолько же проще, насколько я - косатка

Answer (score 0):

Для конкретно этого случая

```
echo reset(reset($xml->time->attributes()));
```

Comment: Вас не затруднит пояснить, зачем в коде `reset`, да ещё дважды? Я посмотрел в [документацию](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php), но фраза "_Set the internal pointer of an array to its first element_" понятным ваш трюк не сделала.

Comment: @VladD reset, помимо прочего, возвращает первый элемент массива. Так как у первого элемента может быть любой ключ, это - самый простой метод. Таким образом здесь разрешается двумерный массив (на самом деле там имитация массива, но это отдельная тема).

Comment: @Etki: А, вижу, там есть ещё массив (тот, в котором индекс `@attributes`), а в нём уже все атрибуты. А почему `$xml->time->attributes()['time']` тогда компилируется?

Comment: @VladD а черт его знает, я не работал с этой штукой, я могу только рассказать, что код делает. Там на самом деле совсем не массив возвращается, который при моей единственной интеракции с ним показался странным по поведению.